# Setting up a Delphi Barchart using TChart

Tags: delphi, charts, teechart

I'm attempting to show statistics on a barchart in delphi using a TChart.

So far I've tried reading up on it but everything I do doesn't seem to work.

I've set up a TChart called 'ChtBarChart' and when the user clicks on a button it should do:

```
ChtBarChart.Series[0].AddXY(0,3);
ChtBarChart.Series[0].AddXY(1,14);
ChtBarChart.Series[0].AddXY(2,3);
ChtBarChart.Series[0].AddXY(3,2);
ChtBarChart.Series[0].AddXY(4,7);
ChtBarChart.Series[0].AddXY(5,4);
```

Whenever I do this I get an access violation error.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does `Series[0]` exist? You can either create series either when designing or running your project, but you need a series before you can add values to it.

Comment: No, do I declare it as a type or variable? Sorry for my lack of knowledge but I've never used a tchart before

Comment: Just Figured out what I needed to do. Thank you very much for the help.